# Android ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(applicationContext) vs ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity.context)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing a swipe feature for an Android app, and I am facing a problem while implementing the **`onChildDraw()`** method of the **`ItemTouchHelper.Callback`**. Every time I swipe an item, I draw a background that covers the itemView's background and a **`Drawable`** on top of it. It works fine, but in another activity, the **`Drawable`** used for the previous swipe sometimes does not render. I noticed that using the **`applicationContext`** when fetching the **`Drawable`** solves the problem, but I don't know why. Can you help me understand why using **`applicationContext`** solves the problem?

```
    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
        if (startX == 0f)
            startX = dX

        if (actionState != ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE)
            return
        val isRightSwipe = dX < 0
        val width = viewHolder.itemView.width

        when (isRightSwipe) {
            true -> {
                drawSms(c, viewHolder)
            }
            false -> {
                drawCall(c, viewHolder)
            }
        }
        val dX = if (isRightSwipe) -dX else dX
        val progress = dX / width

        viewHolder.itemView.alpha = 1f - progress
    }

    private fun drawSms(
        c: Canvas,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ) {
        drawBackground(c, viewHolder, Color.CYAN)
        val drawableBounds = Rect(
            viewHolder.itemView.right - pixelToDp(32),
            viewHolder.itemView.top + pixelToDp(8),
            viewHolder.itemView.right - pixelToDp(16),
            viewHolder.itemView.bottom - pixelToDp(8)
        )
        val drawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(viewHolder.itemView.resources, R.drawable.baseline_call_24, null)

        drawDrawable(c, drawable, drawableBounds)

        val text = viewHolder.itemView.resources.getString(R.string.sms)
        drawText(c, text, viewHolder.itemView.right - pixelToDp(76f), viewHolder.itemView.bottom - pixelToDp(24f))
    }

    private fun drawBackground(
        c: Canvas,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        color: Int
    ) {
        val itemView = viewHolder.itemView

        val leftButton = RectF(
            (itemView.left).toFloat(),
            (itemView.top).toFloat(),
            (itemView.right).toFloat(),
            (itemView.bottom).toFloat()
        )

        paint.color = color
        c.drawRect(leftButton, paint)
    }

    private fun drawDrawable(
        c: Canvas,
        drawable: Drawable,
        bounds: Rect
    ) {
        drawable.setTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.WHITE))
        drawable.bounds = bounds
        drawable.draw(c)
    }

    private fun drawText(
        c: Canvas,
        text: String,
        x: Float,
        y: Float
    ) {
        paint.color = Color.WHITE
        paint.isFakeBoldText = true
        paint.textSize = pixelToDp(20f)
        c.drawText(text, x, y, paint)
    }
```

In this code, using the applicationContext when fetching the drawable solves the problem. but why is it solved? I don't know why.

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAQDg.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcfa8.png)